# How to jump to the start or the end of visual selection in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a motion for moving to the start or end of a visual selection?

I know that <kbd>o</kbd> while in visual mode alternates between the two, but I need to be able to select precisely the start.

The overall goal is to surround a visually selected area with parentheses.

---

**Follow-Up:**

Based on the comments, I was able to implement this using the following macro. The idea is to:

1. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit visual mode;
2. `` `> `` to go to the end of the previous visual selection;
3. `a)` to append a closing parentheses;
4. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode;
5. `` `< `` to go to the start of the previous visual selection;
6. `i(` to insert an opening parentheses;
7. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode again.

For example:

```
map \q <ESC>`>a)<ESC>`<i(<ESC>
```

---

Based on another comment, we have an even more concise solution:

```
map \q c()<ESC>P
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest way to "surround a visually selected area with parentheses" is:

`c`hange the visually selected area to `()` and `P`ut it back in the middle: `c()<ESC>P`

I suggest defining in the `.vimrc` file a new visual-mode command (e.g., `\q`) with that:

```
:vmap \q c()<ESC>P
```

This approach also works with visual rectangular areas (`<C-V>`): it
puts `(` and `)` around each block-line.

Comment: Close, but not quite. If the last character in the visual selection is the last character on the line, the cursor hovers over the character preceding the visual selection. In consequence, using insert ("i") results in parenthesized text being inserted one character further left than intended.

Answer (score 107):

There are two relevant built-in marks holding the positions of the first
and last characters of the last visual selection in the current buffer.
In order to move the cursor to these marks, use the commands `` `< ``
and `` `> ``, respectively (see `` :help `> `` and `` :help `< ``).

Comment: This is exactly the answer _I_ was looking for.  @duckworthd - you should consider clicking accept :-)

Comment: But how do you keep the selection the same?

Comment: @Adrian:  You mean without leaving Visual mode?  If so, you can use the `o` command.

Comment: I'm still missing the functionality I'm looking for. I'd like to move the cursor to the end of the selection without changing it. ```o``` does this if the cursor is at the top, but I want it to stay if it's already at the bottom. ```'>``` would work but it changes the selection

Comment: @rsoren: You can try something like this: ``:vnoremap <leader>ve <esc>`<v`>``. (The same mapping but for the start of selection would be ``:vnoremap <leader>vb <esc>`>v`<``.)

Answer (score 98):

While you are in `Visual Selection` click <kbd>o</kbd>. It will change position of cursor to other end of selection. Then <kbd>O</kbd> to jump back.

Comment: I think it's just `o` to jump vertically back and forth. `O` is to jump horizontally back and forth if you are in visual-block selection.

Comment: @dosentmatter Just to clarify, it looks like in visual-block selection mode, o jumps to the furthest corner from your cursor. O jumps to the farthest point on the same line (just as you describe). This allows easy access to all 4 corners of the block.

Comment: @horta, yes you are right. `o` is more correctly described as diagonal movement than either vertical or horizontal movement.

Answer (score 19):

if you just want to surround a visual selection there has already work been done, namely by tim pope, who wrote [this plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/) called `surround`. It surrounds words or visual selection with delimiters of your liking.

select your visual selection, say `i like vim` hit `S)` to get `(i like vim)` or `S(` to get `( i like vim )`, to change this to `[i like vim]` type `cs]` (change surrounding) and to delete `ds]` to get `i like vim` at last.

Answer (score 12):

If you can't use Surrond.vim, here is one way to do it:

1. Do your visual selection with `v` or `V`.
2. Get out of it with `<Esc>`.
3. Type `` `>a)<Esc> `` to insert a closing parenthesis *after* the last character of the selection.
4. Type `` `<i(<Esc> `` to insert an open parenthesis *before* the first character of the selection.

Comment: I find it weird/interesting that it has to be done it this order - ie. you have to go to end of visual selection (`\`>`) **first** and insert the `)` character before going back to the beginning of the selction (`\`<`) to insert the `(` character.
Doing so the other way around doesn't work because for some reason once you insert the `(` character at the begining of the visual selection vim now thinks the "end" of the visual selection is one character before where it was previously.

Comment: @amy, that's the reason indeed.

Comment: it's weird that is the case though isn't it? I would have thought vim would keep track of the end of the last visual selection in a more intelligent way, to accommodate for situation like this. In reality what must be happening is it defines `\`>` based on whatever character position it is in the current line. So if that was character number 29 and now you've inserted a `(` character earlier in the line, now character 29 (where `\`>` points to) is in fact one character before the where you think it should be, ie. character number 30.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "weird". More like "slightly unintuitive", really. But once you have internalized how marks work, it becomes second nature. The problem is actually more general and abstract than that: if you mess with your preconditions, then your conditions will never be met. With positional things, like items in a list or letters in a strings, starting from the beginning might do that, which makes starting from the end safer.